# How to properly swap numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, swap

I am trying to swap the named columns of a numpy array as shown below, but the function is not behaving accordingly to what I anticipated. I see that the original 'data' is being changed even when I use the deepcopy from the copy module. Is there something that I am missing?

```
import copy
import numpy as np

data = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', float), ('y',float)])

def rot(data, i):
    rotdata = copy.deepcopy(data)
    print(data['x'])
    if i == 0:
        pass
    if i == 1:
        rotdata['x'] = 5-rotdata['x']
    if i == 2:
        rotdata.dtype.names = ['y','x']
    if i == 3:
        rotdata.dtype.names = ['y','x']
        rotdata['x'] = 5-rotdata['x']
    if i == 4:
        rotdata['x'] = 5-rotdata['x']
        rotdata.dtype.names = ['y','x']
    if i == 5:
        rotdata['x'] = 5-rotdata['x']
        rotdata.dtype.names = ['y','x']
        rotdata['x'] = 5-rotdata['x']
    
    return rotdata

  

data1 = rot(data,5)
data2 = rot(data,5)
print(data1)
print(data2)
```

The result is,

```
[1. 3.]
[2. 4.]
[(4., 3.) (2., 1.)]
[(1., 2.) (3., 4.)]
```

Which is indeed against my intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `copy.deepcopy()` does not make a deep copy of the `dtype` object attached to the numpy array. So the data inside the array was copied, but you were switching names `'x'` and `'y'` in the `data.dtype`. So printing `data['x']` gave you a different result, as did the second call `data2 = rot(data,5)`.

You can solve it by adding the following line:

```
rotdata = copy.deepcopy(data)
rotdata.dtype = copy.deepcopy(data.dtype)
```